# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s^2}{(s^2+1)^2}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations

While solving Volterra integral equation 
$$y(x)=\sin x - \int_0^x (x-t)y(t)\ \mathsf dt$$ with Laplace transformation, I found $$Y(s)= \frac{s^2}{(s^2+1)^2},$$ and I dont know to calculate its inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With partial fractions you get
$$\frac{1}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{\left(s^2+1\right)^2}$$
and then looking on a table the result
$$y=\frac{1}{2} (\sin t+t \cos t)$$